# Encode/Decode by certutils.exe on windows

Tags: linux, certificates, windows-subsystem-for-linux

How to decode file on Linux, which was encoded on Windows by [`certutil`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/certutil)?

```
certutil.exe -encode orig.zip orig.zip.txt
```

Comment: The site you linked says `-encode` encodes a file to Base64, so try `base64 -d <orig.zip.txt >orig-decoded.zip`

Comment: Yes, already tried, but unfortunately, it does not work.